# how to insert the data based on ID?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

So, I have 4 tables:

- personal
- honor
- parent
- score

I have done the 3 which they are inserting based on the `ExamineeID`, but I have problem with the `score` which I need also to based on the `ExamineeID`. This is my last problem of my php right now. I have a modal, which ask the user if they are sure to submit or not, and once the user clicked the yes, the data or the score will be inserted. My error says that my score, and rank is undefined variable. This is my code:

## This is my code for the modal:

```
<form method = "POST">
    <div class = "form">
    <button id = "submit" name = "submit"  value = "submit" > SUBMIT </button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3> Are you sure you want to submit? </h3>
    
        <button id = "yes" name = "yes" class = "yes" value = "submit"> YES </button>
        <button id = "no" name = "no" class = "no"> NO </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="myModalLast" class="modalLast">
      <div class="modal-contentLast">
       <a href = "personal.php"> <span class="close">&times;</span> </a>
    
    <div class = "pic">
        <img src="Logo.png" width = "150" height = "150">
    </div>  
        <h3> Full name: <?php echo $_POST["FirstName"]; echo " ";   echo $_POST["MiddleName"]; echo " "; echo $_POST["LastName"];   ?> </h3>  
        <h3> Total items:20<p id = "corrects" name="Score"></p> </h3>  
       <h1> <br>
    
       Rank:<p id = "scoress" name = "Rank">
    </h1> 
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

## This is my php:

```
    $score = $_POST['Score']; 
    $rank = $_POST['Rank']; 
    $ExamineeID;

    if (isset($_POST['yes'])) {
      $stmtscore = $conn->prepare($sqlscore);
      $stmtscore->bind_param("s",$ExamineeID); 
      $stmtscore->execute();
      $stmtscore->bind_result($score, $rank);
      $stmtscore->store_result();
      $stmtscore->fetch(); 
      $rnum = $stmtscore->num_rows;
      $stmtscore->close();
     
      if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
        $INSERTscore = "INSERT INTO score (Score, Rank, ExamineeID) values (?,?,?)";
        $stmtscore = $conn->prepare($INSERTscore);
        
        $stmtscore->bind_param ("ssi", $score, $rank, $ExamineeID); 
        $stmtscore->execute();   
        $stmtscore->close();    
      }
    }
```

This is my script

```
<script>

function loadDoc(scoress) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            scoreElement.innerHTML =  this.responseText;
            console.log('Grade calculation complete');
        }
    }


    let data = "scoress=" + scoress;
    xhttp.open("POST", "examExtension.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhttp.send(data);
}
</script>




 <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
  document.getElementById("corrects").innerHTML = "Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;
});
</script>



 <script>
const scoreElement = document.getElementById("scoress");
const yesButton = document.getElementById("yes");

yesButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
console.log(numberOfCorrectAnswers);
  

  loadDoc(numberOfCorrectAnswers);
  console.log('Calculating grade');
});
</script>
```

Comment: "My error says that my score, and rank is undefined variable.".... ok so what happens when the user clicks on "yes" to submit? Does some Javascript run? If so how does it submit the data? That's where we need to be looking. We cannot see where the score and rank data are coming from, or how you are sending them to the server.

Comment: how can you post the p tag in the form it must an input.the value of the tag is posted further.

Comment: I made an edit to my post @ADyson

Comment: Ok. You're sending a request to the server, but the data you are sending is based on this: `let data = "scoress=" + scoress;`. So that only includes one variable called `scoress`, which doesn't match any of the variables your PHP is looking for. You need to change it to send all the necessary data, with the names correctly spelled as `Score` and `Rank`.

Answer (score 1):

you may update your form with hidden type of score & rank and pass that data in to your ajax JavaScript function, currently you are not passing both score and rank...

bellow update form element with hidden type and javascript function

```html
<form method = "POST">
<input type="hidden" name="rank" value="10"/>
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="10000"/>

    <div class = "form">
    <button id = "submit" name = "submit"  value = "submit" > SUBMIT </button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3> Are you sure you want to submit? </h3>

        <button id = "yes" name = "yes" class = "yes" value = "submit"> YES </button>
        <button id = "no" name = "no" class = "no"> NO </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
...
```

```js
<script>

function loadDoc(scoress) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            scoreElement.innerHTML =  this.responseText;
            console.log('Grade calculation complete');
        }
    }

    let rank = document.getElementById("rank");
    let score = document.getElementById("score");
    let data = "scoress=" + scoress + "&score ="+score + "&rank="+rank;
    xhttp.open("POST", "examExtension.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhttp.send(data);
}
</script>




 <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
  document.getElementById("corrects").innerHTML = "Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;
});
</script>



 <script>
const scoreElement = document.getElementById("scoress");
const yesButton = document.getElementById("yes");

yesButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
console.log(numberOfCorrectAnswers);


  loadDoc(numberOfCorrectAnswers);
  console.log('Calculating grade');
});
</script>
```